# Python package installed in Google Cloud Platform, but getting import error when running Docker image

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, importerror, ta-lib

I have installed this library called Ta-Lib in my GCP in the following way:

```
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
tar -xzf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
cd ta-lib/
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
pip install ta-lib
```

I can then import this library if I run `python` in cloud shell and then `>>> import talib`.

I then proceed to build the docker image of my project with the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /code

COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt

# Give user access to write into the results folder
RUN useradd -m -u 1000 user
USER user
ENV HOME=/home/user PATH=/home/user/.local/bin:$PATH
WORKDIR $HOME/app
COPY --chown=user . $HOME/app

# Run the application:
CMD ["python", "-u", "app.py"]
```

However, after building the Docker image of my project and trying to run it, it gives the following error:

```
username@cloudshell:~/RoboAdvisor (asom-barta-qna-bot)$ python
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import talib
>>> quit()
username@cloudshell:~/RoboAdvisor (asom-barta-qna-bot)$ docker run robo_advisor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/app/app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from finnlp.data_processors.yahoofinance import Yahoofinance
  File "/home/user/app/finnlp/data_processors/yahoofinance.py", line 29, in <module>
    from finnlp.data_processors._base import _Base, calc_time_zone
  File "/home/user/app/finnlp/data_processors/_base.py", line 12, in <module>
    import talib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'talib'
```

I don't understand what is the issue here, and how do I fix it? Why is it saying `talib` is not installed, when it clearly is?

---

I created a shell script called `install_talib.sh` and put it in the directory of my project to install the library like so:

```
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz \
  && sudo tar -xzf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz \
  && sudo rm ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz \
  && cd ta-lib/ \
  && sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr \
  && sudo make \
  && sudo make install \
  && cd ~ \
  && sudo rm -rf ta-lib/ \
  && pip install ta-lib
```

And then I modified my Dockerfile like so:

```
FROM python:3.9

RUN chmod +x install_talib.sh
RUN ./install_talib.sh

WORKDIR /code

COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt

# Give user access to write to write in results folder
RUN useradd -m -u 1000 user
USER user
ENV HOME=/home/user PATH=/home/user/.local/bin:$PATH
WORKDIR $HOME/app
COPY --chown=user . $HOME/app

# Run the application:
CMD ["python", "-u", "app.py"]
```

This time when I try to run it, it gives the following error:

```
username@cloudshell:~/RoboAdvisor (asom-barta-qna-bot)$ docker build -t robo_advisor .
[+] Building 0.6s (6/13)                                                                                                                                                                                       
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 490B                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.9                                                                                                                                             0.2s
 => CACHED [1/9] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.9@sha256:98f018a1afd67f2e17a4abd5bfe09b998734ba7c1ee54780e7ed216f8b8095c3                                                                                0.0s
 => CANCELED [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                0.3s
 => => transferring context: 21.95MB                                                                                                                                                                      0.3s
 => ERROR [2/9] RUN chmod +x install_talib.sh                                                                                                                                                             0.3s
------
 > [2/9] RUN chmod +x install_talib.sh:
#0 0.237 chmod: cannot access 'install_talib.sh': No such file or directory
------
Dockerfile:3
--------------------
   1 |     FROM python:3.9
   2 |     
   3 | >>> RUN chmod +x install_talib.sh
   4 |     RUN ./install_talib.sh
   5 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c chmod +x install_talib.sh" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Comment: Could you please include your dockerfile?

Comment: You need to build the library inside the Dockerfile. Your container does not have access to packages installed on the host. The build result (compiled executable or library) for the package will often be different between the host and the container due to environment differences.

Comment: @JohnHanley Ok, I've edited the question's details to include my steps of trying to do that just now. Please have a look and tell me if what I did is the correct way of doing this.

Comment: @Kristada673 you forgot to add your `install_talib.sh` script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following `install_talib.sh` script in the root directory:

```
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz \
  && tar -xzf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz \
  && cd ta-lib/ \
  && ./configure --prefix=/usr \
  && make \
  && make install \
  && pip install ta-lib
```

And then building the docker image with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /code

COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
COPY ./install_talib.sh /code/install_talib.sh

RUN chmod +x /code/install_talib.sh
RUN /code/install_talib.sh

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt

# Give user access to write to write in results folder
RUN useradd -m -u 1000 user
USER user
ENV HOME=/home/user PATH=/home/user/.local/bin:$PATH
WORKDIR $HOME/app
COPY --chown=user . $HOME/app

# Run the application:
CMD ["python", "-u", "app.py"]
```

Solves the issue.